# subspace of differentiable function

Tags: linear-algebra

The set of differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on the interval $(0,3)$ such that
$f '(2) = b$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{(0,3)}$ if and only if $b = 0$.  How to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suppose that this set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{(0,3)}$, then you know that it is closed under $+$ :

> For all $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^{(0,3)}$ such that $f'(2)=g'(2)=b$, we have $(f+g) '(2)=b$, and thus:
>   $2b=b$ giving **$b=0$**.

Now suppose that $b=0$. We need to prove that our set is non-empty and closed under $+$ and $.$ :

> Taking any two functions $f$ and $g$ in  $\mathbb{R}^{(0,3)}$ and any scalar $k$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(2)=g'(2)=b=0$ you need to prove that $(f+g)'(2)=0$ and $(kf)' (2)=0$.

Comment: Why does being closed under addition imply $(f+g) '(2) = b$?

Comment: @Gavin saying that this set is closed under + means that for every two elements f and g in this set, f+g must remain in this set. Now for f+g to be in this set we must prove that the value of its first derivative at 2 is b.